# SSRS Report - Tablix filter comparing Field Date and Date from another dataset

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have an SSRS report with a table. I also have a dataset CurrentFinancialYear with exactly one record.  I want to filter the table by removing all records which have a date before the start date defined in CurrentFinancialYear.  I am trying to do this using a Tablix filter, like this:

`=CDate(Fields!orderDate.Value)<CDate(First(Fields!startDate.Value, "CurrentFinancialYear")`

I have set the filter type as boolean expecting a true or false from the above.  For some reason however, this returns an error.

I tried the exact same expression in a row in the table, thus returning true or false for each record and indeed it works well there! any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

What you're trying to do might not be the most effective way of filtering your data but only you know that....

To do what you want, in the Tablix filter set the following...

- Expression = `[orderDate]`
- Operator = `<`
- Value = `=First(Fields!startDate.Value, "CurrentFinancialYear")`

I've just tested on a similar dataset and get the filtered results as expected.